# C++, comparator, pointer to function

Tags: c++, compare, function-pointers

I would like to create sorted set of points according to x or y coordinates.

```
typedef std::set <Point2D, sorter> Points;
```

For the type of "Point" I would like to use a different comparators. The first one sorts points according to the x coordinates, the second one according to the y coordinates:

```
typedef std::set <Point2D, sortPointsByX()> Points;
typedef std::set <Point2D, sortPointsByy()> Points;
```

where

```
class sortPoints2DByX
{
    public:

            bool operator() ( const Point2D &p1, const Point2D &p2 );

};

class sortPoints2DByY
{
    public:

            bool operator() ( const Point2D &p1, const Point2D &p2 );

};
```

Is it possible to create a pointer to the constructor sortPoints2DByX/sortPoints2DByY classes in Points declaration

```
typedef std::set <Point2D, pointer_to_somparator_class> Points;
```

and by the need to use any of them?

I need to have one data type can be sorted in two ways.

If this idea is wrong, is there any more suitable solution?

I need to compute median of x and y coordinates...

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is the problem that you need to change how a given set is sorted, or is the problem that you need to be able to pass the set around without having the things you're passing it to have two different methods for the two different set types?

Comment: I have two solutions that are both based on the fact that `::std::set` will take a comparator as a constructor argument.  This will not allow you to reorder a set on the fly, but it will let you use the same type to keep two different orders in two different objects. @André Caron also has a solution based on `::std::set`'s constructor argument.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to create a pointer to the constructor sortPoints2DByX/sortPoints2DByY classes in Points declaration?

No, you cannot take the address a class' constructor.

> I need to have one data type can be sorted in two ways.

You can get around using pointers to functions. Example implementation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

    // Your implementation may differ.
struct Point
{
    int x; int y;
    Point(int x_, int y_)
        : x(x_), y(y_) {}
};

    // For display purposes.
void print(const Point& point)
{
    std::cout << '(' << point.x
        << ',' << point.y << ')' << std::endl;
}

bool OrderByX ( const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs )
{
    return (lhs.x < rhs.x);
}

bool OrderByY ( const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs )
{
    return (lhs.y < rhs.y);
}

    // Type of comparison operator.
typedef bool(*Comparator)
    (const Point&lhs,const Point&rhs);

    // Set used to store points in sorted order.
typedef std::set<Point, Comparator> Points;

int main ( int, char ** )
{
        // Each set ordered with it's own criteria.
    Points by_x(&OrderByX);
    Points by_y(&OrderByY);

        // Insert each point in both sets.
    by_x.insert(Point(1,2)); by_y.insert(Point(1,2));
    by_x.insert(Point(3,1)); by_y.insert(Point(3,1));
    by_x.insert(Point(4,3)); by_y.insert(Point(4,3));
    by_x.insert(Point(2,4)); by_y.insert(Point(2,4));

        // Show that 1st set is in proper order.
    std::cout << "Sorted by X:" << std::endl;
    std::for_each(by_x.begin(), by_x.end(), &print);
    std::cout << std::endl;

        // Show that 2nd set is in proper order.
    std::cout << "Sorted by Y:" << std::endl;
    std::for_each(by_y.begin(), by_y.end(), &print);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

It generates the following output:

```
Sorted by X:
(1,2)
(2,4)
(3,1)
(4,3)

Sorted by Y:
(3,1)
(1,2)
(4,3)
(2,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two solutions, both of which have been tested:

First, code common to both:

```
class Point2D {
 public:
   Point2D(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y) { }

   int getX() const { return x_; }
   int getY() const { return y_; }

 private:
   int x_, y_;
};
```

And the main function...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Points s1(compareByX);
   Points s2(compareByY);
   const int size = 1750;

   for (int x = -size; x <= size; ++x) {
      for (int y = -size; y <= size; ++y) {
         Point2D p(x, y);
         s1.insert(p);
         s2.insert(p);
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

---

Now, for solution 1:

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <set>

typedef ::std::tr1::function<bool (const Point2D &, const Point2D &)> comparefunc_t;
typedef ::std::set <Point2D, comparefunc_t> Points;

bool compareByX(const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b)
{
   return (a.getX() != b.getX()) ?
      (a.getX() < b.getX()) : (a.getY() < b.getY());
}

bool compareByY(const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b)
{
   return (a.getY() != b.getY()) ?
      (a.getY() < b.getY()) : (a.getX() < b.getX());
}
```

---

And the much longer solution 2:

```
class Point2DComparator {
 public:
   virtual bool operator()(const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b) const = 0;

 protected:
   const Point2DComparator &operator =(const Point2DComparator &b) {
      return *this;
   }
   Point2DComparator(const Point2DComparator &b) { }
   Point2DComparator() { }
};

class Point2DComparatorEnvelope : public Point2DComparator {
 public:
   Point2DComparatorEnvelope(const Point2DComparator &letter)
        : letter_(letter)
   {
   }

   virtual bool operator()(const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b) const {
      return letter_(a, b);
   }

 private:
   const Point2DComparator &letter_;
};

class XComparator : public Point2DComparator {
 public:
   virtual bool operator() ( const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b) const {
      return (a.getX() != b.getX()) ?
              (a.getX() < b.getX()) : (a.getY() < b.getY());
   }
};

class YComparator : public Point2DComparator {
 public:
   virtual bool operator() ( const Point2D &a, const Point2D &b) const {
      return (a.getY() != b.getY()) ?
              (a.getY() < b.getY()) : (a.getX() < b.getX());
   }
};

typedef ::std::set<Point2D, Point2DComparatorEnvelope> Points;
XComparator compareByX;
YComparator compareByY;
```

---

They seem virtually (no pun intended) identical in performance.  The second is much more complex, though if you peer at the internals of `::std::tr1::function` you will see that it is extremely hairy.  The second is mainly useful for demonstration purposes.  IMHO, the standard is broken for requiring the stupid envelope/letter hack for the whole thing to work.

Comment: I want to construct KD-tree and I need to quickly and repeatedly compute median...

Comment: That won't work. Because `std::set<>` will make a copy of  a `Point2DSorter`, your instances are going to be sliced and the proper comparison operator won't be invoked.

Comment: @Ian: if your real question is how to implement a KD-tree, there is no standard container that provides this facility directly.

Comment: @André Caron - You're probably right, in which case the implementation of `set` is broken.  And if the standard doesn't say it's broken, the standard is broken.

Comment: @Andre I am writting it myself. But in my opinion, repeated median finding results in significant slowdown of the KD tree construction. i want to do it as much as fast...

Comment: @Omnifarious: nothing is broken. Make `Point2DSorter::operator()` abstract (pure virtual) and it will now stop compiling. In any case, if you tried to compile this, you would get a linker error saying `Point2DSorter::operator()` is not defined, immediately showing you where **your** error is. Do not blame library implementors and standard commitees without *demonstrating* **their** error.

Comment: @André Caron - The specifications for types given for the comparator functors should not require them to have a copy constructor or assignment operator.  Implementations should carefully preserve the passed in reference and only ever store a reference to the passed in comparator object and never make a copy of it.  That is the bug in the standard.  It used to be that implementations also required the type have a default constructor and they constructed a new instance regardless.  Thankfully, those days have passed.

Comment: @Omnifarious: I'm sorry, but that's your *opinion* on how the standard library *should* be designed. Given the current standard, in which `std::set<>` requires copy semantics for the sorting predicate, the solution you proposed does not express what you though it did, let alone compile/link. How this solution was supposed to behave in your idealized version of an inexistant standard is not helpful for the poster and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @André Caron - I fixed it.  And while I agree with you about whether or not its helpful for the poster, I disagree with you about whether or not its on-topic for StackOverflow.